# Lat / Long Truncated when converting list of dicts into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that is returned by a google places API call.

```
places = [
    {
        'geometry': {
            'location': {'lat': 34.0258613, 'lng': -118.4904235},
            'viewport': {
                'northeast': {'lat': 34.0271459302915, 'lng': -118.4890380697085},
                'southwest': {'lat': 34.0244479697085, 'lng': -118.4917360302915}
            }
        },
        'name': 'United States Postal Service',
        'types': ['post_office', 'finance', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
    },
    {
        'geometry': {
            'location': {'lat': 34.0302723, 'lng': -118.4853093},
            'viewport': {
                'northeast': {'lat': 34.0314838302915, 'lng': -118.4838036697085},
                'southwest': {'lat': 34.0287858697085, 'lng': -118.4865016302915}
            }
        },
       'name': "Emperor's College of Traditional Oriental Medicine",
       'types': ['university', 'health', 'point_of_interest', 'establishment']
    }
]
```

I'd like to parse the list of dictionaries and turn them into a pandas DataFrame.

**List of dicts to Pandas DataFrame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(places)
```

Now, I attempt to parse `geometry` column into separate columns of `Lat` and `Long`.

```
df['Lat'] = df['geometry'].str['location'].str['lat']
df['Lng'] = df['geometry'].str['location'].str['lng']
```

However, when I do this, `lat` and `lng` are truncated to 2 decimals by default. This is an issue because I plot them on a map.

```
df_nearby['geometry'].str['location'].str['lat']

34.03
34.03
```

How do I change this? I want the full values to `lat` and `lng` as in the list of dicts.

Comment: How did you find out they are truncated? I ran this code and it has all the decimals for me. The rest of your code is a bit unusual though - storing the dict objects in the dataframe and then the new column contains only the lat & lng for the first row duplicated for all rows.

Comment: When I run your code and print the dataframe I see 34.025861 for lat

Comment: That's just how the float values are being *displayed*. Check yourself, and if needed raise `pd.options.display.precision` to a higher value than 2. You should also be aware of the issue of floating-point precision differences -- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html -- in case that has never come up before.

Comment: @shriakhilc what's the unusual part?

Comment: Oh, that was just because I haven't come across the entire dict being inserted into the df as an object. If that was intentional then don't mind.

Comment: @mechanical_meat setting `pd.options.display.precision` didn't work for me.

Comment: try pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.5f}'.format and change the 5 to whatever value you'd like